During the process of writing data, the cnosdb data node OOM
I am using the latest code 2.4.1,During the process of writing data, the cnosdb data node OOM
the cnosdb log as follow:
2024-05-14T10:07:15.433953191Z  INFO tskv::compaction::flush: Flush: running: FlushReq owner: cnosdb.benchmark, on vnode: 6, low_seq_no: 1809, high_seq_no: 1825 caches_num: 1
2024-05-14T10:07:22.414078339Z  INFO tskv::tseries_family: mut_cache is full, switch to immutable. current pool_size : 15456004457
2024-05-14T10:07:22.449037805Z  INFO tskv::compaction::flush: Flush: running: FlushReq owner: cnosdb.benchmark, on vnode: 6, low_seq_no: 1825, high_seq_no: 1841 caches_num: 1
2024-05-14T10:07:32.316990702Z ERROR coordinator::service: write metrics to cnosdb fail. pre-execution failed: status: Unknown, message: "request timed out", details: [], metadata: MetadataMap { headers: {} }

the client as follow:
Error writing: dial tcp4 xxxx:9902: connect: connection refused

the sys log as follow:
[Tue May 14 10:05:50 2024] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0-1,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-0.slice/session-c160.scope,task=cnosdb,pid=1090994,uid=0
[Tue May 14 10:05:50 2024] Out of memory: Killed process 1090994 (cnosdb) total-vm:171981144kB, anon-rss:129386616kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:283528kB oom_score_adj:0
[Tue May 14 10:05:54 2024] oom_reaper: reaped process 1090994 (cnosdb), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB

The memory pool is only 15G(15456004457/1024/1024/1024). Why does the system log actually occupy 164G(171981144/1024/1024)?
